# Batch script date into variable

Tags: variables, batch-file

```
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do (
set Day=%%k
set Month=%%j
set Year=%%l
set DATE=%%k/%%j/%%l)
```

I am try to get the date into the above variables in a batch script, but currently the date comes out as

```
2011/04/
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I get DATE=04/08/2011 - it based on your windows settings isn't it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't get what you expected because `%DATE%` returns the current date using the windows settings for the "short date format". This setting is fully (endlessly) customizable.

One user may configure its system to show the short date as Fri040811; while another user (even in the same system) may choose 08/04/2011. It's a complete nightmare for a BAT programmer.

One possible solution is to use **WMIC**, instead. WMIC is the WMI command line interface to WMI. **WMI** *Windows Management Instrumentation* is the  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation

```
WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day,Hour,Minute,Month,Second,Year /Format:table
```

returns the date in a convenient way to directly parse it with a `FOR`.

Completing the parse and putting the pieces together

```
 FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
    SET /A TODAY=%%F*10000+%%D*100+%%A
 )
```

Comment: Alternatively: `for /f %%a in ('wmic os get LocalDateTime ^| findstr ^[0-9]') do (set ts=%%a) & set datetime=%ts:~0,8%-%ts:~8,4%` (this gets one `20120623-1617` in the Netherlands right now, hence discarding any timezone).

Comment: @Arjan: I got "~0,8ts:~8,4" in AUS with this %date% format in CMD: 27/11/2012

Comment: @PA This works but I get a "missing operand" error on AUS settings (%date% format in CMD: 27/11/2012). it outputs C:--->(SET /A today=2012*10000+11*100+27 )

 )---->(SET /A today=*10000+*100+
Missing operand.

Comment: This: http://serverfault.com/questions/227345/locale-unaware-date-and-time-in-batch-files worked well for me.

Answer (score 8):

I have derived the shortest from the already given solutions. This works on every system (XP Pro and up):

```
REM ===================================================================
REM CREATE UNIQUE DATETIME STRING IN FORMAT YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS
REM ======================================================================
FOR /f %%a IN ('WMIC OS GET LocalDateTime ^| FIND "."') DO SET DTS=%%a
SET DateTime=%DTS:~0,8%-%DTS:~8,6%
REM ======================================================================
```

Of course you can play with the resulting string format.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I'd use in an XP pro machine and higher.  XP Home does not have wmic.

```
:: timestamp YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set dt=%dt:~0,8%_%dt:~8,6%
echo %dt%
pause
```

and another

```
:: timestamp YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set dt=%dt:~0,4%-%dt:~4,2%-%dt:~6,2%_%dt:~8,2%-%dt:~10,2%-%dt:~12,2%
echo %dt%
pause
```

Comment: I used this in a Windows7 environment.  I must add that it will always give the same result no matter the local settings, no math involved and it includes time.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want:

```
@echo off
:MENU
CLS
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set xsukax=%%a
echo Year=%xsukax:~0,4%
echo Month=%xsukax:~4,2%
echo Day=%xsukax:~6,2%
echo hour=%xsukax:~8,2%
echo Minutes=%xsukax:~10,2%
echo seconds=%xsukax:~12,2%

pause
goto MENU
```

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to use this any way you want

```
:: Date in year, day, month format

FOR /f "tokens=2-4 skip=1 delims=(-)" %%G IN ('echo.^|date') DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%A IN ('date /t') DO (
        SET v_first=%%G
        SET v_second=%%H
        SET v_third=%%I
        SET v_all=%%A
        )
    )

SET %v_first%=%v_all:~0,2%
SET %v_second%=%v_all:~3,2%
SET %v_third%=%v_all:~6,4%
SET DATE2= %MM%_%DD%_%YY%
ECHO. The date is: %DATE2%
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you simply use the following 1 line to create your var (using any var name)?

```
set ymd=%date:~6,4%/%date:~0,2%/%date:~3,2%
```

Comment: It's dependent on the regional settings and format of the %date% output which is variable.  It will work fine on a single machine though, as long as nobody plays with the date settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%a in ('wmic os get localdatetime ^| find "."') do set dts=%%a
set ymd=%dts:~0,8%
set hour=%dts:~8,6%
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script will give local time with timezone (TZ) information, in both true ISO8601 and human format (no 'T'). It converts the TZ offset in minutes into the HHMM format needed e.g. `2019-01-25T08:26:55.347+1300` and `2019-01-25 08:26:55.347+1300` for NZ with DST.

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
set ccyy_mm_dd=%ldt:~0,4%-%ldt:~4,2%-%ldt:~6,2%
set hh_mm_ss=%ldt:~8,2%:%ldt:~10,2%:%ldt:~12,2%
set _fff=%ldt:~14,4%
set tzsign=%ldt:~21,1%
set tzmins=%ldt:~22%
set /a tzHH=(%tzmins%/60)
set /a tzMM=(%tzmins%-(%tzHH%*60))
set /a tzHH=100 + %tzHH%
set tzHH=%tzHH:~1,2%
set /a tzMM=100 + %tzMM%
set tzMM=%tzMM:~1,2%
set ldt=%ccyy_mm_dd% %hh_mm_ss%%_fff%%tzsign%%tzHH%%tzMM%
set ldt8601=%ccyy_mm_dd%T%hh_mm_ss%%_fff%%tzsign%%tzHH%%tzMM%
echo %ldt%
echo %ldt8601%
```

You probably want to remove one of the echo commands

*EDIT* for those wanted a colon in the TZ, change `%tzHH%%tzMM%` to `%tzHH%:%tzMM%`