# How to change the value of a parameter in the batch file according to date?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

The problem is as follows

I have to retrieve logs from a server for that I have made a ".bat" file named "getServerLog.bat" what this file does is it fetches the actual log file that is placed on the server. i.e the contents of "getServerLog.bat" consists of the location on the server where the actual log file is stored but the log file on the server has the following name format "yyyy_mm_dd.stderrout.log" like 2011_11_30.stderrout.log for today's file and this name is autogenerated so in the bat file "getServerLog.bat" I have to parameterize the name so that it always retrieves the latest file. For more explicit information here are the contents of the bat file

**"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" /console /command "option batch on" "option confirm off" "open gtp:*gtp*@10.72.141.68" "get /home/gtp/installed/jetty-6.1.18/logs/2011_08_25.stderrout.log C:\Users\prpandey\Desktop\gtp.log" "exit"**

I need to parameterize the last variable 2011_08_25.stderrout.log to get the latest record or logs. Please help me out regarding this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Eventhough it seems pretty easy, as @Burrhus already showed, the different date formats make it very difficult.

An alternative method, using WMIC, is shown in this post here in SO, 
[Batch script date into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594121/batch-script-date-into-variable/5594319#5594319)

try this code

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
   SET FD=%%F_%%D_%%A
)
ECHO logs/%FD%.stderrout.log
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your dateformat - mine is danish yy-mm-dddd you could do like this.

```
set fileDate=%date:~6,4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" /console /command "option batch on" "option confirm off" "open gtp:gtp@10.72.141.68" "get /home/gtp/installed/jetty-6.1.18/logs/%fileDate.stderrout.log C:\Users\prpandey\Desktop\gtp.log" "exit"
```

Of course this should be altered according to the dateformat.

Comment: thanks for the modification that you pointed out but can u tell how to change it to this format yyyy_mm_dd I will be grateful

Comment: That depends on the dateformat you use.. the code actually just takes the stringvalue and makes three substrings

Answer (score 0):

On my system Aacini's code failes at ('DATE

If I change it to ('echo.%DATE%>NUL') it fails somewhere later (XP SP3). Some explanation on why this code should work regardless the system's current date format would be awesome.