# Copying multiple files and adding date to the name bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy, copying, renaming

I have to make .bat file who does this:

Copies from O:\siirto all files that name starts with "ls". To C:\siirto.
And the name of the output would be same as in the source. But it would add current date to the end of file name.

I tried following just for test and it didnt work of course :D. But it propably explains better what im trying to do than explanation above.

```
echo off
xcopy O:\siirto\ls* C:\siirto\ls%date.txt
pause
```

Of course its not working. 
But is that possible to do with one .bat file. 
Or do i have to do all ls.txt-files their own .bat-files or lines.

Like one for LS1.txt, LS2.txt LS3.txt

```
echo off
xcopy O:\siirto\LS1.txt C:\siirto\ls1%date
pause
```

I have no idea how the %date should add to code and does it need something else to code also?

Im still on child shoes in programming...

thanks

Comment: variable names have a `%` in front AND at the end: it's `%date%`. But it may contain illegal characters for filenames - see JosefZ's  answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to combine the iteration over the files with the `FOR` command and the `%DATE%` environment variable. Read `HELP FOR`, paying attention to the %~ expansion syntax, and try the following code.

```
for %%a in (o:\siirto\ls*) do (
   echo copy "%%a" "c:\siirto\%%~na-%date%%%~xa"
)
```

after careful testing, remove the `echo` command.

---

You might generalize a bit your code, by moving some configurable information out of the loop

```
set src=o:\siirto\ls*
set dest=c:\siirto
for %%a in (%src%) do (
  copy "%%a" "%dest%\%%~na-%date%%%~xa"
)
```

and, in case the `%date%` command returns invalid characters, read my accepted answer to this SO question [Batch script date into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594121/batch-script-date-into-variable/5594319#5594319) and then change the variable to the one that contains the current date with the appropiate format.

Comment: This was the first i tested. It worked so... :D thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 0):

The `%date%` could contain characters that are [not allowed in file names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx). Try next locale-independent approach:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions

for /F %%g in ('
  wmic OS get LocalDateTime /value^|findstr "="
  ') do for /F %%G in ("%%g") do set "_%%G"

set "_LocalDateTime=%_LocalDateTime:~0,8%"

for /F "delims=" %%G in ('
  dir /b O:\siirto\ls*.txt
  ') do echo copy /B "O:\siirto\%%G" "C:\siirto\%%~nG_%_LocalDateTime%%%~xG"
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `%date%` by default contains the current date - but the format of the date depends on user-settings, so it may contain separators such as `/-.` may have a dayname and space-separator and may have the day-number and month-number with suppressed-leading-zero.

There are many articles on SO about formatting date-strings to a usable format - the format yyyymmdd is recommended since that format is automatically by name into a chronological sequence.

Note that it's not a good idea to use the variable `date` since that date is established and maintained by the system and any user-setting will override the assumed system-seting. Use virtually any other valid variable name (the same comment applies to `random` and `time` amongst others).

So, assuming you assign the date in the format that you want to a variable `today` then

```
for %%a in (o:\siirto\ls*.txt) do (
   echo(copy "%%a" "c:\siirto\%%~na%today%%%~xa"
)
```

would perform the required copy. `%%~na` means the name part of the filename in `%%a` and `%%~xa` the extension part. Variables should normally be accessed by using `%varname%`. The filenames are `"enclosed in quotes"` to ensure that separators within the filenames (such as <kbd>Space</kbd>) are regarded as regular characters not having the special meaning of a separator.

The required COPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files. Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file copied`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in one line using `forfiles`[1](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)

```
    forfiles /P O:\siirto /M ls*.txt /C "cmd /c copy @path C:\siirto\@fname-%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%.txt"
```

Here `forfiles` looks at all the files in the specified path `/P` that match the mask `/M`, then runs a command on each file found `@path` to copy it to the new location with the date appended. `@fname` here just gives you the file name without the path or extension.

The `%date%` variable generally yields something along the lines of 25/06/2015, or even Thu 25/06/2015, depending on your settings. This is why you need to specify parts of it.

`%date:~6,4%` selects from the seventh to the 11th digit in the date (the counting starts from 0), which yields the year. `%date:~3,2%` gives you the month (or the day depending on where in the world you are from) and `%date:~0,1%` gives you the day (or month, again depending on where you are).

You might have to play around with this a little bit to get the result you want.