# Batch File to Copy files to another Folder, the new folder should get created with that instances Time-Stamping & Date-Stamping

Tags: batch-file

I have an application which creates logs & if I don't take backup of those logs it will overwrite them, so I have created a script for backing up my files and putting them into a new folder, the name of the new folder is getting created with that instances time-stamping & date-stamping. Now the date & time format I have at my workplace is different than what I have mentioned in script so the folder is getting created with a gibberish name, so I want it to follow the same date & time format, the one I have at work i.e. Short Date: M/d/yyyy; Long Date: dddd, MMMM d, yyyy; Short Time: h:mm tt; Long Time: h:mm:ss tt

```
"  @echo off
set hh=%time:~-11,2%
set /a hh=%hh%+100
set hh=%hh:~1%
set dateseed=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%hh%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%

if not exist "D:\AHSM1_logs\%dateseed%" mkdir "D:\AHSM1_logs\%dateseed%"
cd "D:\Backup\%dateseed%"
move D:\"Program Files (x86)"\Entrust\"Enrollment Server for Web"\logs\cdalog.log-* D:\AHSM1_logs\%dateseed%   "
```

Comment: Not the answer, but still: do not quote intividual parts of paths, quote whole paths, like this: `"D:\Program Files (x86)\Entrust\Enrollment Server for Web\logs\cdalog.log-*"`!

Answer (score 1):

check the [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5594319/8906305) by [PA.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30447/pa)

[Check Solution 2](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/sortdate5_xp.txt)

problem is setting date using **`%date%`** you can use **`WMIC`** to retrieve date and time